# Class not found error for any glass api

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I [configure](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start#for_android_beginners) **eclipse ADT** for glass development successfully.
Then I create a sample project and try to develop google glass card or timelineitem.

when I compile and run, an error occurred from **android tuntime**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.glass.app.Card
```

this error also occurring for

```
com.google.android.glass.timeline.TimelineManager
```

**Error Log**
[image]
How can I solve it?

Comment: If you go to your project's properties dialog in Eclipse and click on the Android section, which SDK is checked?

Comment: glass development kit sneak peek, api level 15

Comment: What version of the software is your Glass device running?

Comment: Glass Software Version is XE11

Comment: can you give us a screenshot ? What IDE? Eclipse? What other projects do you have open in that workspace ?

Comment: I am using ADT Bundle for Linux 64-bit. I have one android project in this ADT. Now try to do glass app.thats it

Comment: Have you tried doing Project->Clean in Eclipse?

Comment: no. i am try to do using my existing ADT. should I close all the project and start again?

Comment: in ATD, select the menu option "project" -> "clean" then try to run again

Comment: I did, but still same error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I have the same error. Have tried everything I can think of. What's your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your project to compile with the Glass GDK.

Make sure you're targeting 15, have the GDK downloaded as per the other answer, and then:

Select your project on the left side of the screen, open project poperties (alt-enter, or right click -> properties), go to Android tab, scroll down to Android 4.0.3, and in that section will be the Glass Development Kit Sneak Peak.  Check the box next to this, hit ok and everything should start working.

EDIT:

Just to make sure, your manifest should have this line:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are targeting API 15 and that you installed the glass development Kit.
See the Picture:

[image]

Comment: Yes I am using API 15. otherwise I cannot access Glass development environment