# Can I use my own voice command in Google Glass app with Mirror API?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I want to use my own or custom voice command for a Google Glass app using the Mirror API.
Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: If you're able to use the GDK (rather than the Mirror API) you can register custom voice commands for invoking your app.

Comment: but my GDk is not working properly. please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120028/class-not-found-error-for-any-glass-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, although you need to request them from Google. See https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/contacts#declaring_voice_menu_commands for more information about voice commands with Mirror. That page refers you to https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form to apply for a voice command.